# Htaccess - RewriteBase with images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm doing some fun with htaccess. I'm uploading images to a certain directory, and when I access this image via browser, it redirects to another page that shows this image properly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ media/show/index.php?image=$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

But I cant access this image in that file due this htaccess. I mean, on index.php, if I try to `<img src="../image.jpg"/>` it does not load. Probably due this htaccess.

**Sample:**
http://lucasveiga.com/media/m4exleFWz4.jpg

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using absolute URLs?

Comment: Open your site in Firebug and see which URL is giving you 404

Comment: Yes. I already tried absolute URLs and in Inspector it gives me the correct url. I'm attaching a sample URL to you see.